# A query regarding constant $\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}}$ in Coulomb's Law

Tags: electrostatics, units, coulombs-law, si-units

In our physics class we were discussing about Coulomb's Law and equation for the electrostatic force between two points:
$$F_{e}=\frac{Q_{1}Q_{2}}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2}$$

From the equation a query arose which is for what reason does the constant involve $4\pi$.

Comment: The link I've suggested has itself been closed as a duplicate of a couple of other questions. However I think it is the best match to your question and the answers to it are relevant.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of rationalisation and mathematical convenience. $4\pi$ corresponds to the whole solid angle, which usually simplifies when you deal with Gauss' theorem. In other words, you can simply redefine a constant $k$ to be any multiple of another constant, $1/E_0$ in this case.

Comment: Can you explain it more explicitly with some kind of equations or diagrams.I understand calculus but I am new to Electricity & Magnetism.

Comment: Following John Rennie's suggestion, here is a relevant link on SE http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74254/