# Analogue of $\varepsilon_0$ for gravitational mass?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, physical-constants

In electric fields, we usually define the dielectric constant in vacuum as:
$$K_C=\dfrac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}$$

Why don't we define the gravitational analogue, "digravitational" constant:
$$\Delta_0=\dfrac{1}{4\pi G_N}$$

Is that constant used and have someone defined it before? Surely, it is, but I would like a reference...

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/113006/is-4-pi-g-the-true-most-fundamental-gravitational-constant